# VB.NET binding WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, binding

I have this in my XAML file:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" 
        FontSize="100" 
        Content="{Binding Path=ButtonText, 
                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                          Mode=TwoWay}" 
        Margin="0,185,0.133,0.4"/>
```

And this is my .vb file:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Interface"
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Properties"
Public Property ButtonText As String
    Get
        Return propText
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        propText = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonText")
    End Set
End Property
#End Region

Private propText As String

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    'If propText Is "Test" Then
    propText = "Suc6"
    'ElseIf propText Is "Suc6" Then
    'propText = "Test"
    'End If
End Sub
End Class
```

If I press the button, his Content should show "Suc6", but it's a fail. What did I do wrong? I've been reading up on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26210/Moving-Toward-WPF-Data-Binding-One-Step-at-a-Time and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 but can't figure out what I did do wrong.

Comment: Are you setting DataContext? Post XAML code.

Comment: This is the entire Xaml code: http://pastebin.com/hBgQabC6 There is probably a lot of code that could be done better.

Comment: You don't need the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay on the button.  The button content is not editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your VB version and I tested it works for sure.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MainWindow
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.DataContext = Me
    End Sub

    Private propText As String
    Public Property ButtonText As String
        Get
            Return propText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            propText = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonText")
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        ButtonText = "Suc6"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace propText with ButtonText in the Button_Click

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ButtonText= "Suc6"
End Sub
```

Also I would do the following in the constructor to set the DataContext

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = this;            
    }
```

Comment: Make the additional change which I suggested. this.DataContext = this

Comment: You do realize I'm programming this in VB.NET and not C#? I do know C# but I wouldn't have an idea where to put this in VB.NET

Comment: Thats what I realized just now ...Lol :)

Comment: @Krowi You cannot find MainWindow constructor in VB?

Comment: No I can't, never needed it

Comment: Some VB.NET binding examples http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/650456/Databinding-Examples-in-WPF-for-VB-NET